# How to get latest patch list by latest date applied rpm -qa -last command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, patch

**Objective:**
To find latest patches set packages list applied for unix vm

**Currently what we do:**

I am manually checking `rpm -qa -last` command to verify all the patches that applied on a linux machine. but it shows patches applied on all previous history dates, but I want to filter out resultset so that I can see patches only by latest date.

Comment: Why not just pipe it to `| head` - you could do some funkiness to awk / grep this output if you want which can be used to feed another call with the extracted date grep'd. The answer by bhm here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/centos-list-the-installed-rpms-by-date-of-installation-update gives you a decent starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rpm -qa --last | awk 'NR==1 {x=$3$4$5} x==$3$4$5'
```

Using `--last` will sort the output from `rpm` with the most recent entries first.  The `awk` statement will then, on the first record (`NR==1`) record the date of the first entry (fields 3 to 5 contain the day, month, year), and on all records only output those lines which match this date.